# How to avoid to go back after click on back button of browser in rails 5?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Rails 5 and jQuery. After logging in, the home page is displayed, but when I click on the back button of browser, it will show me log in page again.

When I click on the back button, I want it to redirect to the home page, Please help me to solve this problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How did I solved this problem?

I used the jQuery to solve this porblem.. add those lines inside the script tag of html login page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function preback(){
    window.history.forward();
  }
  setTimeout("preback()", 0);
  window.onunload=function(){null};
</script>
```